# how to download attachments from Salesforce using c#?

Tags: attachment, c#

I am a beginner in Salesforce. I have uploaded the attachments on Salesforce using C# but I do not have any idea to download them using C#.

Comment: You can use the /services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment API endpoint if you have the attachment Id.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm

Comment: My question would be however you have uploaded attachments using C#, try the same for downloading. If you need to have the physical files along with the csv data, you will need to convert the body field of attachment object (which is base64) converted.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. There was issue with the await method in connecting with Salesforce and Downloading attachments as well. I figured out and resolved the issue by using Wait() to both methods. Thanks again.